# dplyr() grouping and getting counts - error message Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a data frame (df) with two variables, location and weather.

I'd like a  wide data frame (dfgoal), in which the data is grouped by location and in which there are three new variables (weather_1 to weather_3) with counts for the observations in the original weather variable.

The problem's that when I try to use dplyr()::mutate() I only get TRUE/FALSE output rather than counts, alternatively an error message: `Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "logical"`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
df <- data.frame(location=c("az","az","az","az","bi","bi","bi","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca"),weather=c(1,1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,2))
```

Desired outcome (df):

```
dfgoal <- data.frame(location=c("az","bi","ca"),weather_1=c(2,0,2),weather_2=c(1,2,2),weather_3=c(1,1,1))
```

Current code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(location)  %>% mutate(weather_1 = (weather == 1)) %>% mutate(weather_2 = (weather == 2)) %>% mutate(weather_3 = (weather == 3))
df %>% group_by(location)  %>% mutate(weather_1 = summarise(weather == 1)) %>% mutate(weather_2 = summarise(weather == 2)) %>% mutate(weather_3 = summarise(weather == 3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krzysztof's solution is the way to go, but if you insist on using `tidyverse`, here is a solution with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(location, weather) %>%
  summarize(count = count(weather)) %>%
  spread(weather, count, sep="_") %>%
  mutate_all(funs(coalesce(., 0L)))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   location [3]
  location weather_1 weather_2 weather_3
    <fctr>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1       az         2         1         1
2       bi         0         2         1
3       ca         2         2         1
```

Comment: I like that I get the column names with this solution

Answer (score 4):

It is super simple with function called *table*:

```
df %>% table  

        weather
location 1 2 3
      az 2 1 1
      bi 0 2 1
      ca 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Krzysztof's answer wins for simplicity, but if you want a tidyverse-only solution (`dplyr` and `tidyr`):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(location, weather) %>% 
    summarize(bin = sum(weather==weather)) %>%
    spread(weather, bin, fill = 0, sep='_')
```

This results in:

```
location    weather_1   weather_2   weather_3
az  2   1   1
bi  0   2   1
ca  2   2   1
```